# Docker Swarm mode : what does mean the status "Assigned"?

Tags: docker

Docker version : 1.13.1

Sometimes the service doesn't start and stay on the status "Assigned".
It only happens on some nodes, when i "drain" the node, the application starts very well elsewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It means that the task has been assigned to a node but the node has not accepted it.

> Tasks run through the allocator, which allocate resources such as network attachments which are necessary for the tasks to run. When the allocator has processed a task, it moves the task to the **PENDING** state.
>
> The scheduler takes **PENDING** tasks and assigns them to nodes (or verifies that the requested node has the necessary resources, in the case of global services' tasks). It changes their state to **ASSIGNED**.
>
> From this point, control over the state passes to the agent. A task will progress through the **ACCEPTED**, **PREPARING**, **READY**, and **STARTING** states on the way to **RUNNING**. If a task exits without an error code, it moves to the **COMPLETE** state. If it fails, it moves to the **FAILED** state instead.

https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/blob/master/design/task_model.md#task-lifecycle